# What is one hot encoder's categorical_features used for?

Tags: python, machine-learning

So I am encoding one of the categorical feature in my data using one hot encoder, but I can't understand a parameter in it. Can you guys help me with, what does it used for. Parameter is: categorical_features= [0]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features= [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Answer (score 3):

The aim of the `OneHotEncoder` is to encode categorical integer features as a one-hot numeric array. The `categorical_features` argument, as stated in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) is used to:

> Specify what features are treated as categorical.

This might be used in the case where we want to directly feed all the features to the encoder, i.e. categorical and numerical, and specify the set of features that we want as one-hot. Here's an example of how you could use it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4,5,6], 'col2':[1,2,3]})

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features= [True, False])
onehotencoder.fit_transform(df.values).toarray()

array([[1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 1., 3.]])
```

In this case we specified a `mask` indicating which features we want as one-hot, so in this case the first one. `categorical_features` also works with an array of indices, `categorical_features= [0]` would yeild the same result.

Comment: One hot encoding is just one type of embedding ;)

Answer (score 0):

This parameter is well explained in [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

> Specify what features are treated as categorical.
>
> > 'all': All features are treated as categorical.
> >
> > array of indices: Array of categorical feature indices.
> >
> > mask: Array of length n_features and with dtype=bool.

BTW, this parameter will be deprecated.

> Deprecated since version 0.20: The categorical_features keyword was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the `ColumnTransformer` instead.

What are features in ML (machine learning) these are *independent* variables of input or our measurements. The number of features is something we define.
We one-hot encode the features to express the features are independent.

Answer (score -1):

```
categorical_features : 'all' or array of indices or mask, default='all'
    Specify what features are treated as categorical.
    - 'all': All features are treated as categorical.
    - array of indices: Array of categorical feature indices.
    - mask: Array of length n_features and with dtype=bool.
    Non-categorical features are always stacked to the right of the matrix.
    .. deprecated:: 0.20
        The `categorical_features` keyword was deprecated in version
        0.20 and will be removed in 0.22.
        You can use the ``ColumnTransformer`` instead.
Attributes
----------
categories_ : list of arrays
    The categories of each feature determined during fitting
    (in order of the features in X and corresponding with the output
    of ``transform``). This includes the category specified in ``drop``
    (if any).
drop_idx_ : array of shape (n_features,)
    ``drop_idx_[i]`` is the index in ``categories_[i]`` of the category to
    be dropped for each feature. None if all the transformed features will
    be retained.
```

you can refer to this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)                                          if you want to dig deeper go through this [github link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23089993)

Comment: I agree with this. I faced this issue in the past and I provide links. Now I have put links and content that can help to resolve this problem